# Django - get file from db by its url

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement a secure access to files. This is my view serving static files:

```
from django.views.static import serve

class ServeStatic(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("login")

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user == Document.objects.get(url=self.kwargs["path"]).owner:
            return serve(request, kwargs["path"], kwargs["file_root"])
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

The point is that I cannot get the condition to work. Is it even possible to get a file by its URL, or I need to choose a very different approach of serving files?

My Document model:

```
 class Document(models.Model):
     owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               verbose_name=_("Owner"), related_name="owner")
     document = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_handler, verbose_name=_("Document"))
```

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Does `Document.objects.get(url=self.kwargs["path"]).owner` return a user ID?

Comment: Ah, maybe I should post my models as well, it raises an attribute error with url not being an attribute

Comment: You might want to look into sending the `X-Accel-Redirect` (nginx) or `X-Sendfile` (Apache) headers instead of using the `serve()` view. The server will still call your app, but the header will tell Nginx/Apache to serve the file from disk, rather than sending the file content through WSGI. This should give much better performance.

Comment: In my case the performance does not matter at all, the files are under 5 KB. But maybe it helps someone else :)

Comment: Performance is not the only issue -- though usually the most convincing. `static.serve()` is simply not meant for production use, per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve): "This view is **not** hardened for production use and should be used only as a development aid; you should serve these files in production using a real front-end web server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I will pass to `dispatch` cleaned data (after validation). I'm not saying you're not doing that. Next thing, I wouldn't use the same part of file path which locates files on your machine as it is in url. If you're using `Document` model, so you can change url to something which doesn't tell anything about document. Let's say even uuid:

```
import uuid
print uuid.uuid4().get_hex() # python 2.7
print (uuid.uuid4().hex)     # python 3.x
```

according to uuid sent in url I will search proper document in my database:

```
 class Document(models.Model):
     owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               verbose_name=_("Owner"), related_name="owner")
     uid = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False)
     document = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_handler, verbose_name=_("Document"))
```

You can then query using:

```
class ServeStatic(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = reverse_lazy("login")

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        doc = Document.objects.get(uid=self.kwargs["uid"],
                                   owner=request.user):
            return serve(request, doc.document, kwargs["file_root"])
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know WHY it is not working, I am asking HOW to make it working. I do not have any forms here, the files are accessed by their URL directly. Thanks for the UUID, it looks nice, I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, right now I am implementing it. I will let you know if it is working

Comment: Hm, what actually should the workflow look like? An user types `mydomain.com/uploads/somefile.txt` in the browser, I need to check whether he or she is the owner of the file and if yes, then let him or her download the file. How to make use of the UUID here?

Comment: mydomain.com/uploads/66e3161a175b43f9b8cf97197fea6a41 , where this long number is uid from your model.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand it. You saved me a night of work, thanks :)

Comment: Well, the only issue is that the UUID trick spoils the filename on download, including its extension :(

Comment: You have under doc.document relative path to file right? So you can then serve it as static file. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Right now I have this:
`doc = Document.objects.get(uid=kwargs["uid"])`

`if request.user == doc.owner:`

`return serve(request, doc.document.url, kwargs["file_root"])`

Comment: Could you put in your question serve method or from where you import it if it's some kind of module?

Comment: it's just a regular Django view, nothing special

Comment: The best way if instead of serve static file, use something different like this one: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/ function ``send_file``.

Comment: I made that. The goal is to have the URL like domain/1234567890abcdef1234567890/yourfile.txt. The downloaded file is named like the URL from the last slash onwards, resulting in yourfile.txt here.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you have it! In the future, it's good to have it implemented, that on the end is only uuid and when you hit URL with, then you send file like in my last comment.